# How to customize the endnote counter using enotez?

Tags: endnotes, enotez

I want to add parentheses to endnote marks. When I use the `endnotes` package, I just redefine one command:

```
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{(\arabic{endnote})}
```

Now I've switched to the `enotez` package and this command does not work.

How to customize the endnote counter using `enotez`? 
I don't want to change its format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mark-cs` key has to be updated to something other than `\textsuperscript`. Below I've added the parentheses via an auxiliary macro `\putinparen`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{mark-cs={\putinparen}}
\newcommand{\putinparen}[1]{\textsuperscript{(#1)}}

\begin{document}

Something\endnote{first}. Something\endnote{second}.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively `\renewcommand*\enotezwritemark[1]{(\textsuperscript{#1})}`